# Python: execute a long script without block the main process

Tags: python

I'm using GNU/Linux and python 2.7.3, I'm new on it. I'm trying to execute a long installed system process like `ffmpeg` using the `Popen()` command to avoid blocking the main python process. I can't make it work.

My first attempt was to use threads, but it is a bit complicated, because the graphical interface doesn't work properly (and I suppose there has to be a better way)

Then I tried fork, but it is like killing flies with tanks.

Now I'm trying to use `Popen`, I saw a lot of references to its use in the internet, but I'm not running it properly I think. Maybe I'm misunderstanding the examples.

I've tried:

```
##command is ffmpeg like that works ok
p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
```

I've tried also:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(command,stdin=PIPE, shell=True)
```

Usually I get an error or a sequentcial behavior, the command ends and then the main program resumes. What am I missing?

The command part:

```
    global vidSource
    global srtSource
    global done
    size = "3"

    font = "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSerif.ttf"
    command = 'mencoder ' + '"' + vidSource + '"' + " -oac copy -ovc lavc -lavdopts threads=2 -sub " + "'" + srtSource + "'" + " -subcp -utf8 -font "+ '"'+ font+ '"' + " -subfont-text-scale " + size + " -o " + '"' + vidSource + '2'+'"'
```

Comment: What error are you getting?  You do know, `Popen` uses `fork()` (on linux) for creating new processes... If you didn't want to fork for some reason, Popen is not a viable solution.

Comment: Sorry, i forget to specify. I've tried to reproduce the error, but i get with the two comands i post a sequencial behaviour. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be on a good track. Just use

```
p = subprocess.Popen(command)
```

You can check whether the process has ended with a `p.poll`, as described in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html)

Note that using `shell=True` is **not** recommended (for security reasons), so you should try not to use it unless you have a very good reason.

As described in the documentation, your `command` must be a **list** of arguments. If you build a long string, you should use `shlex.split(command)` to transform it into a string while preserving the `"` and forth (of course, you need a `import shlex` in your module).

Comment: I get an error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fer/myapp/myapp/MyappWindow.py", line 129, in on_addSubtitle_clicked
    p = subprocess.Popen(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

This is the only way i get an error, so i think the command is oK. Thanks for the help!

Comment: `No such file or directory`.. means you are trying to access/execute something that doesn't exist

Comment: command = 'mencoder ' + '"' + vidSource + '"' + " -oac copy -ovc lavc -lavdopts threads=2 -sub " + "'" + srtSource + "'" + " -subcp -utf8 -font "+ '"'+ font+ '"' + " -subfont-text-scale " + size + " -o " + '"' + vidSource + '2'+'"' 

Where the vid sources are passed by user. I have tested it with a os.system call and are OK for it.

Comment: @ferbuntu: please post the commands in your question with the proper formatting, it's gettng hard to read them in comments.

Comment: @PierreGM -- The problem here is obvious. OP is passing a string to `Popen` which is being interpretted as executable to find.  But, there is not executable named `mencoder "...`.  Op needs to use `p = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command))`  (or I suppose use `shell=True`)