# how to run python file in script without blocking

Tags: python, ubuntu, subprocess, screen, blocking

```
a=subprocess.Popen(['python3 part.py'], shell=True)
a.communicate(m.text)
if run_second_bot==True:
    a.communicate(m.text)
else:
    a.communicate(b.text)
```

I use to sign in to telegram from other script, but this way block the **main script** in first line, and other lines did not written, my Operating system is Ubuntu. I use `os.system()` it also block my main script.

**Is there any way to run 2 script in 2 different terminals or screens ?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: execute a long script without block the main process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603604/python-execute-a-long-script-without-block-the-main-process)

Comment: yeah but ```FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:``` it give me this error , how can i get the path to popen